# what is bad about this TextWriter method?

Tags: c#

[alt text http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/7827/textwriter.jpg](http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/7827/textwriter.jpg)

the tf.txt file has 0 bytes and when calling this method several times over the loop I get:

the process cannot access "   " because it is being used by another process

Comment: Sorry, try again. Too hard to read.

Comment: Small pictures of code are not legible.

Comment: Can't read the code, the picture is tiny.
Please attach the code as text, and use the "Code Sample" cutton to make it look snappy. This way, we can copy the code and test it ourselves... and also, seeing the code is kinda mandatory.

Comment: From which line does the exception come? Can you post the stacktrace. Preferably as text.

Comment: Try adding a "using()" statement around your streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're not closing the `TextWriter`. Thus the file handle remains open, so you can't create another one writing to the same file.

Use a `using` statement:

```
// Consider using File.CreateText instead, btw
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...))
{
    ...
}
```

I'm surprised that your file is empty, admittedly... did it throw an exception the first time you called it, e.g. in `GetTerms()`? That would explain it. You might need a using statement for `IndexReader` as well, by the way - we can't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

Why is tw.Close commented out?  This might be the cause of "is being used by another process" since the file would be held open until closed.